# I'm trying to UPDATE some fields in my table in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I need some help with this, sorry, I am new in VBA and I am trying to run a update query which should obtain a value from a variable and update an already existing table. This is done using VBA. On executing no error message is shown but the table isn't updated with the new value. The code is as follows:

```
Query = "UPDATE Results " & _
        "SET fk_Report='" & Report & "'" & _
            ",fk_Name='" & Namevar & "'" & _
            ",fk_Age='" & Agevar & "'" & _
            ",fk_Sex='" & Sexvar & "'" & _
        "WHERE [Count]='" & Countvar & "'" & _
            ",[Positives]='" & Posvar & "'" & _
            ",[Negatives]='" & Negvar & "'" & _
            ",[Unknow]='" & Unkvar & "';"
    CurrentDb.Execute (Query)
```

If somebody can help...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the commas in the where clause

```
Query = "UPDATE Results " & _
    "SET fk_Report='" & Report & "'" & _
        ",fk_Name='" & Namevar & "'" & _
        ",fk_Age='" & Agevar & "'" & _
        ",fk_Sex='" & Sexvar & "'" & _
    "WHERE [Count]='" & Countvar & "' " & _
        "AND [Positives]='" & Posvar & "' " & _
        "AND [Negatives]='" & Negvar & "' " & _
        "AND [Unknow]='" & Unkvar & "';"
CurrentDb.Execute (Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

use AND instead of , (comma) after WHERE clause